# Phpmyadmin - Procedure : Command out of sync

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, procedure

I created a procedure in my database without any error, but when i want to use it, i get the following error : 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'

It happens in phpmyadmin, i have no idea what i am doing wrong...

Here is my procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE recupererNotesANoter (IN id_utilisateur INT, IN id_evaluateur INT, IN id_annee INT, IN id_sprint INT, IN id_equipe INT, IN id_matiere INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT idAnneeScolaire, idSprint, idEquipe, idUtilisateur, nom, prenom, NULL idNote, NULL note, idMatiere, libelle, coefficient
    FROM pgl_matieresetudiantevaluees
    WHERE (idUtilisateur = id_utilisateur OR id_utilisateur IS NULL)
          AND (idAnneeScolaire = id_annee OR id_annee IS NULL)
          AND (idSprint = id_sprint OR id_sprint IS NULL)
          AND (idEquipe = id_equipe OR id_equipe IS NULL)
          AND (idMatiere = id_matiere OR id_matiere IS NULL)
          AND (FIND_IN_SET(id_evaluateur, evaluateurs) = 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(id_evaluateur, evaluateurs) IS NULL)
    UNION
    SELECT idAnneeScolaire, idSprint, idEquipe, idUtilisateur, nom, prenom, idNote, note, idMatiere, libelle, coefficient
    FROM pgl_notesetudiants
    WHERE idEvaluateur = id_evaluateur
          AND (idAnneeScolaire = id_annee OR id_annee IS NULL)
          AND (idSprint = id_sprint OR id_sprint IS NULL)
          AND (idEquipe = id_equipe OR id_equipe IS NULL)
          AND (idMatiere = id_matiere OR id_matiere IS NULL)
          AND (idUtilisateur = id_utilisateur OR id_utilisateur IS NULL)
    ORDER BY idUtilisateur;
  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope you can help me

EDIT : When i run 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE recupererNotesANoter', i get :

```
sqlMode : STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

Comment: What does "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE recupererNotesANoter;" returns ? And what do you mean exactly by "when I use it" ? in phpmyadmin ? in your php code ?

Comment: I use 'call recupererNotesANoter' in phpmyadmin to get the result. I edit with the result of SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE